# How to get SWT Font family name in Java?

Tags: java, fonts, swt

I am in the process of converting a programming using the AWT package to SWT. While working with the fonts I can't seem to find an SWT equivalent to

```
Font f = new Font();
String s = f.getFamily();
```

Is there a similar way in SWT to get the name of the font that I am just over looking?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. When I call `.getFontData()` it returns an array of `FontData`. So once I just pulled a single Font data out I got my info.